# Angular table with 4 columns different items

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I was busy making a table with Angular, one row has to look like this:
[image]

The problem is i get the same products in one row or only one column in a row. Look:

[image]
[image]

```js
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

input_product: string;
products = ['kaas', ' prei', 'loempia', 'wcpapier', 'bananen', 'nootjes'];
// products = [];


onClick_addProduct() {
    this.input_product = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input_product')).value;
    this.products.push(this.input_product);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table  class="table table-sm table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let product of products"  >
          <td >{{product}}</td>
          <td >{{product}}</td>
          <td >{{product}}</td>
          <td >{{product}}</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this: [Display a Table using Components with Angular 4](https://codeburst.io/display-a-table-using-components-with-angular-4-f13f0971666d)
but i got problems with the last part: *(app-table-row 
      [character]="ch" 
      [columns]="columns")*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let c of columns">{{c}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let ch of characters | async" 
      app-table-row 
      [character]="ch" 
      [columns]="columns">
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think it's a convention error, but I'm not sure...

Is there a easy way to show the products in 4 columns? Because i can't seem to find how to list the products with an index. :(

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON you're working with please?

Comment: products is a an array of strings, what would you expect to happen that isn't based on that?

Comment: @AustinTFrench Nothing in particular, just makes it easier when I'm creating a StackBlitz if I can copy and paste some relevant data.

Answer (score 2):

Id recommend using `divs` instead of a `table`, this is not tabular data.

Try this:

```
<div class="product" *ngFor="let prod of products">
  {{prod}}
</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.product {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1joyvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

Comment: Ah I see your point! Thanks, actually I was thinking the wrong way.. hmmpf

Answer (score 1):

I made a change to the data (Actual objects)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwbc2q

Products now looks like this:

```
  products = [{name:"tire1", line:"impressive"},{name:"brand X", line: "economy plus"},
  {name:"hard plasticos",line:"urban destroyer"},{name:"happy ride", line:"smooth and sticky"}]
```

And in Angular:

*ngFor is just a foreach loop: So `foreach product in products make a row` looks like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products"  >
     <td >{{product.line}}</td>
     <td >{{product.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Looks good actually, thanks! I will use this to improve and add some mocking JSON data.